# readAsText() function giving file path as result instead of content

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read the text contained into a .txt file on my computer with a function to print it inside a div in my html but I keep getting the path of the file as result instead of the text contained in it.

```js
const path = 'c:\\Users\\Demostenes\\Desktop\\sub.txt'
const blob = new Blob([path], {type: 'text/plain'});
const file = new File([blob], 'sub.txt', {type: 'text/plain'});

const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
  console.log(reader.result);
};

reader.readAsText(file);
```

Comment: You can run a local file server to request the content of local files. Here's an example of one using [Deno](https://deno.land/): https://docs.deno.com/runtime/tutorials/file_server#using-the-stdhttp-file-server

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a file using the string in the path variable as its contents.

If you want to read a file from the user’s disk then it **must** be selected using a file input.

Web pages are not allowed, for security reasons, to help themselves to any file the user has without it being explicitly selected by the user.

Comment: The [File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API) can also be used _without a file input_.

Comment: This is not going to be uploaded on a server. Its meant to stay an html file on my machine so its not going to be a proper web page. My goal its to use it exclusively this way. I think that since the code its just running locally, this should be possible.

Comment: @SalvatoreImprota — You think wrong.

Comment: I made it. Thank you <3